# How to correctly rescue this NameError

Tags: ruby

I encountered this NameError

```
>> v
NameError: undefined local variable or method `v' for #<Rex::Post::Meterpreter::Ui::Console::CommandDispatcher::Core:0x00000002871728>
    from (irb):1:in `cmd_irb'
    from /home/txjoe/git/metasploit-framework/lib/rex/ui/text/irb_shell.rb:54:in `block in run'
    from /home/txjoe/git/metasploit-framework/lib/rex/ui/text/irb_shell.rb:53:in `catch'
    from /home/txjoe/git/metasploit-framework/lib/rex/ui/text/irb_shell.rb:53:in `run'
    from /home/txjoe/git/metasploit-framework/lib/rex/post/meterpreter/ui/console/command_dispatcher/core.rb:390:in `cmd_irb'
    from /home/txjoe/git/metasploit-framework/lib/rex/ui/text/dispatcher_shell.rb:430:in `run_command'
    from /home/txjoe/git/metasploit-framework/lib/rex/post/meterpreter/ui/console.rb:105:in `run_command'
```

I opened the file `metasploit-framework/lib/rex/ui/text/irb_shell.rb` at line 54, which supposedly causes the error:

```
catch(:IRB_EXIT) do
  irb.eval_input
end
```

Given that it was a name error, I added the statements

```
catch(:IRB_EXIT) do
  begin
    irb.eval_input
  rescue NameError => e
    puts(e)
  end
end
```

but I still get the error. Am I using the rescue at a wrong place?

This happens while using the irb shell from a meterpreter session in metasploit.

Comment: I think the log is pretty clear : `undefined local variable or method 'v'`. `v` isn't defined, there's no need to investigate metasploit code.

Comment: @EricDuminil, Yeah that's correct, although i wish to handle this better, to just print out the error instead of the entire stack trace

Comment: Why? If you want to solve the problem : define `v`. If you don't care about `v`, don't try to display it in IRB when it's not defined.

Comment: @EricDuminil, I understand, just trying to understand why what I tried didn't work. Because from what I know, the rescue statement should work. Right?

Comment: `puts(e)` displays the error. So yes, the error is still displayed. If you don't want to see the error, don't display it inside the `rescue` block.

Comment: @EricDuminil puts(e) should display just the error right? Not the stack trace? Because I see both.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138727/discussion-between-tabish-imran-and-eric-duminil).